# File.Stream for a file on S3?

Tags: elixir

Is it possible to stream a file from a URL ? ex: Amazon S3 ?

I tried to do:

```
stream= File.stream!(public_s3_file_path)
```

I got error, although the file is there and public:

```
** (File.Error) could not stream "filepath...": no such file or directory
    (elixir) lib/file/stream.ex:78: anonymous fn/2 in Enumerable.File.Stream.reduce/3
    (elixir) lib/stream.ex:1240: anonymous fn/5 in Stream.resource/3
    (elixir) lib/stream.ex:785: Stream.do_transform/8
    (elixir) lib/stream.ex:1403: Enumerable.Stream.do_each/4
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:216: Task.Supervised.stream_reduce/10
    (elixir) lib/stream.ex:570: Stream.run/1
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:85: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: &Stream.run/1
    Args: [#Function<0.55381211/2 in Task.Supervisor.build_stream/5>]
```

Here is the minimum code to try:

```
stream= File.stream!("https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/trackware.staging.schools/school-2/uploads/process%3A15073648797260")
Task.start_link(Stream, :run, [stream])
```

the error:

```
16:19:49.569 [error] Task #PID<0.168.0> started from #PID<0.165.0> terminating
** (File.Error) could not stream "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/trackware.staging.schools/school-2/uploads/process%3A15073648797260": no such file or directory
    (elixir) lib/file/stream.ex:78: anonymous fn/2 in Enumerable.File.Stream.reduce/3
    (elixir) lib/stream.ex:1240: anonymous fn/5 in Stream.resource/3
    (elixir) lib/stream.ex:570: Stream.run/1
    (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:85: Task.Supervised.do_apply/2
    (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Function: &Stream.run/1
    Args: [%File.Stream{line_or_bytes: :line, modes: [:raw, :read_ahead, :binary], path: "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/trackware.staging.schools/school-2/uploads/process%3A15073648797260", raw: true}]
```

Any idea? maybe `File.stream` is only for local files?!

Comment: It's possible in the sense that S3 supports getting an exact byte range of an object in a bucket. So you can make multiple requests, for successive byte ranges, until you get the entire file. You can see this approach here: https://github.com/ex-aws/ex_aws/pull/196/files#diff-50dc7f8117b1be05295369ca23e8fa73 . Check out the `perform` function. It uses GenStage workers to do a parallel download. The workers can probably be adapted to feeding into a Flow ( https://hexdocs.pm/flow/Flow.html#from_stages/2 ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.stream` only works for local files. You need an HTTP client to read from HTTP servers. The [`httpoison`](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison) package for example supports streaming requests in which the response is sent to a process via messages as and when the remote server writes something to the connection socket. You can read more about it in httpoison's [README](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison).

```
iex> HTTPoison.get! "https://github.com/", %{}, stream_to: self
%HTTPoison.AsyncResponse{id: #Reference<0.0.0.1654>}
iex> flush
%HTTPoison.AsyncStatus{code: 200, id: #Reference<0.0.0.1654>}
%HTTPoison.AsyncHeaders{headers: %{"Connection" => "keep-alive", ...}, id: #Reference<0.0.0.1654>}
%HTTPoison.AsyncChunk{chunk: "<!DOCTYPE html>...", id: #Reference<0.0.0.1654>}
%HTTPoison.AsyncEnd{id: #Reference<0.0.0.1654>}
:ok
```

(An example from the README of httpoison.)

Comment: is it a good idea to download the file using `httpoison` then stream it with `File.stream` ? or `httpoison` would return a stream that can be used as stream returned by File.stream ?

Comment: There is also a library called [ex_aws](https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws), which also has S3 stream support AFAIK

Comment: @simo streaming requests in HTTPoison do not implement the `Stream` protocol so they're not compatible with how `File.stream` functions. If the file is small you could just do a normal request and use the returned string? or are the actual files larger than the sample URL you gave?

Comment: @JonasDellinger isn't that library meant for accessing S3 buckets you own? Does it support streaming files from public S3 URLs?

Comment: Would `File.stream!` work on a file at a nother node? I might end-up downloading the file, do the streaming, then remove it.. well?

Comment: @Dogbert By having a quick peek over it, I guess you're right. So it's not a solution if you don't have access to the bucket behind it

Comment: I do own the bucket, but stream seems not implemented yet https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws/blob/be04190415885518096dada1d9b567e456eaec86/lib/ex_aws/s3/download.ex#L84

Comment: @JonasDellinger is this what you mean ? https://github.com/CargoSense/ex_aws/blob/6e0ad79250f5441e2636afaed8fc3bacb5d35ba6/lib/ex_aws/operation/s3.ex#L92

Comment: @simo This seems just for deleting objects, `S3DeleteAllObjects`

Comment: I see, so, it seems not possible,, by the way, here is my minimal code currently for local file streaming: https://elixirforum.com/t/file-stream-for-a-file-on-s3/9066/9?u=sabri

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of the future readers, this had been [made possible](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_aws_s3/2.5.2/ExAws.S3.html#download_file/4-streaming-to-memory) in ExAws.S3:

```
fs = File.stream!("file.txt")

ExAws.S3.download_file("example-bucket", "path/to/file.txt", :memory)
|> ExAws.stream!()
|> Stream.into(fs)
|> Stream.run()
```